# Jquery Tools scrollable problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-scrollable

I'm having an issue where after the 10th page, the next page seems to show many pages as it scrolls.

Please refer to my page here: 
http://rh-photography.com.au/Weddings/Album-Samples/Album-3#

Click "Next" 10 times. On the 11th time, you will notice that it actually starts from the beginning of the scrollable and scrolls all the way to the 11th image. Same story with the 12th etc.

I can't see any differences in my code at all that would cause this.

Could someone please help me?

I'm using the following:
jquery 1.4.4
jquery tools 1.2.5/tiny
(jquery ui 1.8.2)

Also see anyone with the same problem might like to check my forum post on jquery tools site if that helps: http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/35/54693 (But my question is the same here as it is there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a bug in jQuery.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7193

It's been fixed in 1.4.5.  But that is unfortunately not out, yet.

If you can roll back, it doesn't exist in 1.4.2.  So that's a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Okay people, found the issue.
It's documented here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/35/54010

Basically if the .items (in a standard install) goes beyond left: -10000px, you get this issue. each item in my install is around 1000px so it makes sense that the 11th one causes the problem.

Now to find a work around... :(